# Organizing database for multiple-source data entry

Tags: database-design

I have a web application that contains data structured like this:

- Review (has properties such as title, type, text, year, etc.)
- Software (in many-to-many relationship with reviews)
- Language (in many-to-many relationship with reviews)
- Owner (in one-to-many relationship with reviews)

There is a web form that is used to manage all reviews, software, languages, owners, and so on, so that data is correctly displayed on the site.

Now, there's a need to allow third parties to modify data in those reviews (basically, only their own review), after which their modifications should undergo a review process, and then would be merged with existing data.

What's the best practice (regarding database design) when such a need arises?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You essentially need a versioning mechanism.  This allows for multiple instances of each `REVIEW` over time.

Some people do this by keeping a separate review table for pending and historical versions (e.g. `REVIEW_HISTORY` and others (including WordPress) put a version number and status in the main article table and filter by these accordingly when displaying the article to various types of user (editor, public, administrator, etc.)

**Edit:**
Since OP's question asked about best practices for database design, I didn't address the question of access control.  This was a deliberate choice on my part since what is required is a **data-driven** access control mechanism that permits users to edit only those records which they own.  The ownership is established in the data model and must be imposed by *application logic*.  It is not a matter of role-based security, although role-based security is probably also a good idea for this or just about any system.

In my view OP's question is about *versioning*, not about *access control*.

Comment: I'm finally back to tackling this problem. You are right about enforcing access control in application logic, that has (almost) nothing to do with database design. Versioned database using multiple tables seemed even before like the most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to implement a permissions system. The classic way of doing this is to introduce the concepts of "user", "role", and permission.

For instance, you might create a user role "My content editors", who have rights to create reviews for any type of project, and modify and publish any review. Users Alice and Bob might be in that role.

You'd also create a role called "CompanyX content creator", who has rights only to create reviews for products a, b and c. User Xavier might be in that role.

You then need to modify your content creation and publication process to understand the permissions required for each step. You probably also need to introduce the concept of "status" (and possibly version, as @JoelBrown writes) for reviews - the initial status might be "draft", and only users in the role "My content editors" can move it to status "published".

This is a pretty standard construct for this kind of requirement; it's easier if you have a well-factored application in the first place.